# How to do routing "walking path" inside specific premises?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm trying to achieve routing "walking path" inside specific premises (Hospital). I'm using osmdroid and osmdroid bonus pack. I have spend losts of time. Still not success. Does anyone achieved like this.

[image: This is the point i'm trying to get the internal routing]

By now i tried

```
roadManager.addRequestOption("routeType=pedestrian");
```

and all other available rooting types available [here](http://open.mapquestapi.com/guidance/#basicoptions)
and it gives result only where roads available.

[image: Refer the image]
 Can someone suggest the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

I'm trying something as below.

[image: I'm trying something like this.]

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one for a few reasons.

1. Osmdroid has issues as zoom levels > 20. In fact, 20 should be your max. Finding a map source for zoom 20 is also difficult, however the mapsforge adapter should help with that. You'll need a high zoom level in order for this to be useful to the user.
2. OSM data is generally a series of nodes and paths that connect the nodes called `ways`. The vast majority of these nodes and ways are for roadways. These nodes and ways are the only thing we have for calculating walking or driving directions. You should be able to get directions to the closest address.
3. If you have osm data for inside the building, that's great, but now you have a GPS/location issue. GPS generally doesn't penetrate indoors.

So no real answers here, but hopefully this will help you identify some of the challenges ahead.